# Why use both workers and streaming together in Papa Parse?

Tags: papaparse

I used papa parse initially with workers enabled to avoid locking the browser thread. However, now that I'm using streaming the browser thread doesn't lock even with workers disabled.

I'm confused as to why? What reason would someone want to use both workers and streaming? Why doesn't the documentation mention that streaming can overcome locking the browser too?

Comment: Streaming and workers solve two different problems. Streaming solves the problem of handling large files. Worker thread solves the problem of unresponsive web page. So, follow-up: How big is your file? What browser are you using, and what kind of system specs are you running on? (edit: I'll happily expand this into an answer but I need to know more about your specific question.)

Comment: @Matt 100,000 rows by 16 columns. Tried it on both chrome and firefox. Core i7 processor. Web page remains responsive without workers enabled. I had thought it would become unresponsive and needed workers to be enabled but it doesn't?

Comment: I was more interested in file size on disk, but from what you've said that sounds like a tiny file and a fast processor. How long does it take to process?